# Run Time Error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, android, exception, fatal-error

Hi am new to Android App development and i was trying to implement a simple OCR App found here: https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR
Am using android studio, i found some errors that had to do with permission which i fixed but now i am getting this error:

```
03-31 20:07:55.010      822-822/com.example.zakaria.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at engenoid.tessocrtest.MainActivity.onPhotoTaken(MainActivity.java:210)
            at engenoid.tessocrtest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:134)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.zakaria.myapp-10.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.zakaria.myapp-10]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
            at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:44)
            at engenoid.tessocrtest.MainActivity.onPhotoTaken(MainActivity.java:210)
            at engenoid.tessocrtest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:134)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the main Activity:

```
package engenoid.tessocrtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.zakaria.myapp.R;
import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple";
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";

    // You should have the trained data file in assets folder
    // You can get them at:
    // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
    public static final String lang = "eng";

    private static final String TAG = "SimpleAndroidOCR.java";

    protected Button _button;
    // protected ImageView _image;
    protected EditText _field;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };

        for (String path : paths) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                }
            }

        }

        // lang.traineddata file with the app (in assets folder)
        // You can get them at:
        // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
        // This area needs work and optimization
        if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
            try {

                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");
                //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                        + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                //gin.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        _field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
        _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        _button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

        _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting Camera app");
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    }

    // Simple android photo capture:
    // http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

    protected void startCameraActivity() {
        File file = new File(_path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);

        if (resultCode == -1) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "User cancelled");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

            int rotate = 0;

            switch (exifOrientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

            if (rotate != 0) {

                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            }

            // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
        }

        // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

        Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

        baseApi.end();

        // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
        // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
        // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

        Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

        if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
            recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
        }

        recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

        if ( recognizedText.length() != 0 ) {
            _field.setText(_field.getText().toString().length() == 0 ? recognizedText : _field.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
            _field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());
        }


    }

}
```

And this is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zakaria.myapp" >



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="engenoid.tessocrtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So if i need to post any thing else please tell me and thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're missing a .so file "lept"

Comment: @GabeSechan this file should be added on the Android side meaning the Smart phone or in the project files ?

Comment: how did you guys solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

@GabeSechan you are right i went through the app files and there was supposed to be a file by that name, doing some further Google search i learnt that that file is supposed to be generated when building the tess-two library used in this app, i think i didn't do that right.
thank you so much.